# HTML canvas gets blurred on fullscreen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I want to paint some rectangles on my canvas. This canvas should have a fullscreen size.

The correct view without resizing the canvas:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const canvas = $('#c')[0];
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const rectHeight = 100;
    const verticalPosition = i * rectHeight + (i + 1) * 10;
    ctx.strokeRect(10, verticalPosition, 200, rectHeight);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

The view with a resized canvas:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const canvas = $('#c')[0];
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const rectHeight = 100;
    const verticalPosition = i * rectHeight + (i + 1) * 10;
    ctx.strokeRect(10, verticalPosition, 200, rectHeight);
  }
});
```

```css
#c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

I don't want the elements grow bigger. Just the canvas should have a bigger area to draw on. The elements on the canvas should keep their size. Otherwise they get blurred.

Comment: Instead of scaling, you can set the width and height of the canvas in pixels with JavaScript, when the window has loaded and when it’s resized. As an aside, you don’t need jQuery.

Comment: but how do I get the correct pixels for fullscreen on all displays?

Comment: `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare the canvas `width` and `height` in your JavaScript. Set the dimensions to the `width` and `height` of the window.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const canvas = $('#c')[0];
  // Set the canvas size
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const rectHeight = 100;
    const verticalPosition = i * rectHeight + (i + 1) * 10;
    ctx.strokeRect(10, verticalPosition, 200, rectHeight);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: is there a CSS equivalent for `window.innerWidth` ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with canvas.

Comment: @MatthiasHermsen you seem to be misunderstanding the issue. Using CSS to resize the element is not possible if you want the intrinsic dimensions of the canvas data to match the actual dimensions of the canvas.

Comment: How can we extend @sol solution to work with window resizing too>?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, solved it just by setting `width` and `height` properties to `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` properties of the canvas element. Inner dimensions of the canvas are calculated from `width` and `height` attributes and they are surprisingly not set by setting them to 100% in CSS. So the working code for you is:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const canvas = $('#c')[0];
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const rectHeight = 100;
    const verticalPosition = i * rectHeight + (i + 1) * 10;
    ctx.strokeRect(10, verticalPosition, 200, rectHeight);
  }
});
```

```css
#c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Have a nice day.

Answer (score -4):

I think this is common problem with CSS. I would rather use JS :

```
canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth; 
canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
```